Why is Sagemaker Endpoint invocation giving an "Failed to deserialize Error"
I am trying to invoke model(Falcon 40B) via sagemaker endpoint, I get the below error when I make the call.
Error:-
Failed to deserialize the JSON body into the target type: invalid type: string "{"name": "john mclain"}", expected struct CompatGenerateRequest at line 1 column 29"
sagemaker_runtime = boto3.client("sagemaker-runtime", region_name='ap-south-1')
endpoint_name = "jumpstart-dft-hf-llm-falcon-40b"
inference="huggingface-llm-falcon-40b-instruct"
jsonstr={"name": "john mclain"}
#Gets inference from the model hosted at the specified endpoint:
response = sagemaker_runtime.invoke_endpoint(
EndpointName=endpoint_name, 
ContentType="application/json",
Body=(jsonserializer.serialize(json.dumps(jsonstr))),
InferenceComponentName='huggingface-llm-falcon-40b'
) 


By passing Body=jsonserializer.serialize(json.dumps({"name": "john mclain"}))
I think you're double-serializing to
"{\"name\": \"john mclain\"}"

...rather than if you just pass in Body=json.dumps(...), for
{"name": "john mclain"}

(For what it's worth, I'd probably rename your jsonstr variable since it's the request payload in dictionary form, not a string - so the name is a bit misleading).
